# How do I create a schema with google datastore (in javascript)?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express, google-cloud-datastore, nosql

I am writing a Nodejs application that uses Google Datastore. I just want to know how I can set up schema with google datastore for the authentication process. Basically, how can i do **the code below** with Google Datastore:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

local            : {
    email        : String,
    password     : String,
}

});

// generating a hash
userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

// checking if password is valid
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I am just starting to use Nodejs and Google Datastore, so I am sorry if this question seems very basic.

Answer (score 7):

Your example with the gstore-node library would be almost the same as with Mongoose:

```
// The connection should probably done in your server.js start script
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
var ds = require('@google-cloud/datastore')
var gstore = require('gstore-node');
gstore.connect(ds);

// In your user.model.js file
// --------------------------
var gstore = require('gstore-node');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var Schema = gstore.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({
    email    : {type: 'string', validate:'isEmail'},
    password : {type: 'string'},
});

// custom methods (https://github.com/sebelga/gstore-node#custom-methods)
// generating a hash
userSchema.methods.texts = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

// checking if password is valid
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.get('password'));
};

// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = gstore.model('User', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this library, I am just starting myself and it's closest I've found so far: https://github.com/sebelga/gstore-node